Issue while using .NET Standard 2.0 library that uses Store API in WPF .NET Core 8.0 type of project
Hi fellow MSFT developers,
I have created a sample project for your convenience, available at
https://github.com/JiyaDesai-FandCo/WpfAppdotnet8
We have existing code in Library (of type .NET Standard 2.0) that heavily uses Store APIs, Addon and stuff. and we reuse this library in all our Store App projects. Currently this library is used in WPF (.NET 4.8) and UWP projects and all is running fine.
Problem occurred when we decided to create WPF project with .NET Core 8.0 That's where we are unable to use the library.
Now let me explain the sample project on github, which you can download, explore and help us to identify issue or workaround. The aim is to reuse library in all kind of projects. (WPF with .NET 4.8, UWP and WPF with .NET Core 8.0 ). Keeping in mind we are going to publish it on Store.
Also Note: while you debug, please always run packaging projects only.
ClassLibrarydotnetStandard2 :

Has reference Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts version 10.0.22621.2428 nuget package
Has a function that calls Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
public string LibraryFunctionToGetPackageName() { ... }
Assume it has other functions related to Store API

xWpfApp1 : WPF with .NET Framework 4.8

References ClassLibrarydotnetStandard2
Calls function : var s = c.LibraryFunctionToGetPackageName();
(Do not run xWpfApp1 directly, instead run xWpfApp1_Package.)

xWpfApp1_Package : Packaging project for xWpfApp1

Compile and Run.
Click on button #1 to call library function
You should see, it does succeed.

WpfAppdotnet8 : WPF with .NET Core 8.0

References ClassLibrarydotnetStandard2
Calls function: this.Title = c.LibraryFunctionToGetPackageName();
(Same, do not run WpfAppdotnet8 directly, instead run below
packaging project.)

WPFdotnet8_PackageToPublishToStore : Packaging project for WpfAppdotnet8

Compile and Run the package project
Click on button #1
You will see Error during library call. Exception:
"System.PlatformNotSupportedException"

We want to resolve this error, so that we can use library successfully in WpfAppdotnet8
Hope I was able to explain.
Thanks & Regards
Awaiting your response very curiously.

Why don't you just get rid of .NET standard, keep 4.8 (or move it to .NET 8) and .NET 8 together https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/

You have already posted the same question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/78450352/3137337 by different account. Perhaps you no longer need to keep the previous question?

@SimonMourier We have lots of code in library which is currently in use by WPF and UWP apps.  migrating library may break old apps.

No it shouldn't break many things. Have you tried to replace it by .NET Framework 4.8 or .NET 8? Code should be very compatible in this direction since .NET standard is just a list of contracts, an (now outdated, was always made for transition) abstract intersection of real platforms.

.NET 6 and later use the target framework moniker option to consume Windows Runtime APIs:
Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps
This means that you should build multiple versions of your class library:
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'"
                    Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts" Version="10.0.22621.3233">
    <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

You should also include the OS version in the TFM in the .NET 8 project:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>


Absolutely astounding,  @mm8 Sir!  Your solution worked like a dream!  Thank you immensely!
